# Why does XCode close this dialog as i try to connect to IBOutlet?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

As soon I click the **connect** button, XCode closes. I have used SQLite for swift. Before then, it was working fine - but now I am seeing the following problem:

[image: Problem]

Comment: Your tag showing XCode7, may be you should try the new XCode 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the Derived Data folder from Xcode? Sometimes when Xcode is acting weird or crashing for no reason, deleting this folder solves the problem.

Close Xcode by quitting the program.

Go to Finder, press Alt, Open the menu "Go" in the system options on the top of the screen, click on "Library", release the "Alt" button.

Open the folder Developer, open the folder Xcode and delete the folder Derived Data.

Open Xcode again. Try connecting the IBOutlet again.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Instead of creating an IBOutlet from the storyboard into the into the code, try the following: In the code, make the IBOutlet (@IBOutlet weak var test: ...). Than go to the storyboard and open the design corresponding to the controller. Go to the last tab of the inspector of the ViewController (make sure you select the whole viewcontroller in the storyboard). In that list should somewhere be your fresh created IBOutlet. Link the bullet after the IBOutlet by dragging from the bullet to the corresponding view/button/label/... on the storyboard. Does this work?

Comment: follow what?I can see nothing. Please help

Comment: Sorry, pressed the enter-button too quickly!

Comment: Now it seems to be working.. but can you  explain what is wrong with this xcode. I have wasted the whole day looking for an answer, neither I got answer, nor any reason why the xcode is being crushed.It was working fine before i started to work with SQLite using objective - c bridge. i am using FMDB.
Thanks in advance. sorry for poor grammar

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what is wrong with your version of Xcode. This is simply just another way of connecting IBOutlets (and IBActions too btw) in code with the storyboard. But if you're using Xcode 7.x, I'm suggesting that you update Xcode to version 8. Be aware that if you're developing an app that still needs to support iOS 7 or prior, that isn't possible in Xcode 8. Xcode 8 only supports iOS 8 and later.